# Finding space $T_2$ so $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U+T_{2}$ but not $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U\oplus T_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I have the following space:

$$U=Sp\left\{ B_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\
4 & 1
\end{pmatrix},B_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1\\
3 & 2
\end{pmatrix},B_{3}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 11\\
7 & -2
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

I'm trying to find $T_1,T_2$ in $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ so $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U\oplus T_{1}$ and $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U+T_{2}$ but not $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U\oplus T_{2}$.

First of all I found out that ${B_1,B_2}$ is base of $U$.  Also I marked $T_{1}=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\} $.

I have proved that $dim(T_{1}+U)=4$ and so $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U\oplus T_{1}$ but which $T_2$ I can use so I get $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U+T_{2}$ but $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})=U\oplus T_{2}$?

Comment: a very trivial example of such a $T_2$ is $T_2 = M_2(\mathbb{R})$; clearly $M_2(\mathbb{R}) = U + M_2(\mathbb{R})$, but $M_2(\mathbb{R}) \neq U \oplus M_2(\mathbb{R}) $

Comment: why $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})\neq U\oplus T_{2}$

Comment: The notation $M_2(\mathbb{R}) = U \oplus T_2$ means by definition $M_2(\mathbb{R}) = U + T_2$ and $U \cap T_2 = \{ 0\}$; but if we choose $T_2$ to be the whole space $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, then clearly $U \cap T_2 = U \cap M_2(\mathbb{R}) = U \neq \{ 0\}$